# Compare values in sequential rows in a longitudinal dataset

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataset with mistakes in a date variable.
Here is an example:

ID 1 has as first date in the first row `2013-07-17`. The difference to study begin (`2012-08-29`) is `321` days. In the next row the visit date is `2013-02-15` and the difference to study begin (`2012-08-29`) is `169` days. Therefore there must be an error with the date of the visit `2013-07-17` because the visits are in ascending order.

I tried:

```
dat$DifferenceDateerror <- "no"

i <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat[i,"DifferenceDate"] > dat[i+1,"DifferenceDate"] & !is.na(dat$DifferenceDate)[i])
  {dat$DifferenceDateerror[i]=="yes"}
}
```

but got the following error:

> error in if (dat[i, "DifferenceDate"] > dat[i + 1,  : 
>         missing value, where TRUE/FALSE is needed

I would like to find out where the Date must be wrong.

Comment: I also tried:test <- function(dat,AbstandVisite){
  newdat <- rep(0, length(dat))
  if(AbstandVisite[1]>AbstandVisite[2]){
    newdat <- "yes"
  } 
  
  return(newdat)
}

Comment: Your access number of rows + 1 in your loop, please try to replace `1:nrow(dat)` by `1:(nrow(dat)-1)`. You also have to isolate the `NA` condition, your first conditions might fail

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code to: 


dat <- subset(dat,!is.na(dat$DifferenceDate))
dat$DifferenceDateerror <- "no"
i <- 1 for(i in 1:(nrow(dat)-1)){ 
if(dat[i,"DifferenceDate"] > dat[i+1,"DifferenceDate"] {dat$DifferenceDateerror[i]=="yes"} 
}

but I get only "no's" as result. The code does not find the mistakes.

Comment: Use `<-` or `=` instead of `==` to store `yes`

Comment: Try `df$DifferenceDateerror <- c("no", "yes")[c(FALSE, diff(dat$DifferenceDate) < 0)]`

Comment: Thank you so much! Both worked and I leant a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add `"yes"`/`"no"` values where the current date is greater than next date, we can use `diff` to compare consecutive dates and assign values accordingly.

```
df$DifferenceDateerror <- c("no", "yes")[c(FALSE, diff(dat$DifferenceDate) < 0)+ 1]
```

Or similarly with `head` and `tail`

```
df$DifferenceDateerror <- c("no", "yes")[c(FALSE, head(x, -1) > tail(x, -1)) + 1]
```